# Solving the steady heat equation with slight nonlinearity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system, bessel-functions, heat-equation

I am modelling steady Joule heating within an annulus, cooled on the inner and outer edges.

I would therefore like to solve the axisymmetric heat equation with internal generation, i.e.

$$\nabla^2T + \frac{q_v}{k}=0 \label{eqn:'Heat'}$$

However, I would like to account for temperature in both the volumetric rate of generation $q_v = J^2\rho$ and conductivity $k$. Both electrical resistivity $\rho$ and $k$ have linear constitutive models (temperature coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively) referred to reference conditions $(\rho_0,T_0)$ and $(k_1,T_1)$ respectively, shown below:

$$\rho(T) = \rho_0(1 + \alpha(T-T_0))$$
$$k(T)=k_1(1+\beta(T-T_1))$$
Note that reference conditions for each property need not be the same, hence the different subscripts.

To simplify, the governing equation may be written:

$$\nabla^2T + \frac{A+BT}{C+DT} = 0; \quad A \equiv \frac{\rho_0J^2}{k_1}(1-\alpha T_0), \quad B \equiv \frac{\alpha\rho_0J^2}{k_1}, \quad C \equiv 1-\beta T_1, \quad D\equiv\beta$$

Thus, the equation is now slightly nonlinear (a modified Bessel equation).

I have been able to solve a version with $\beta = 0$; the resulting equation is linear and admits a solution that is a sum of Bessel functions (constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ depending on boundary conditions):

$$T_{\beta=0}(r) = c_1J_0(r\sqrt{B}) + c_2Y_0(r\sqrt{B}) - \frac{A}{B}$$

I would like to know whether there is an analytic solution more generally. I have attempted various variable substitutions (e.g. see below) but cannot find anything to remove the non-linearity.

By writing $u(r) \equiv C + DT$, Equation \ref{eqn:'Heat'} becomes (using prime notation for brevity):

$$u^{\prime\prime}+\frac{u^{\prime}}{r}+\frac{E}{u}+B = 0, \quad E \equiv AD-BC$$

Note that if there is no variation with temperature $E=0$ and we recover the canonical solution $$T_{E=0}(r) = c_1\log(r) + c_2 -\frac{q_vr^2}{4k}$$

Any insight or assistance would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Your $\rho$ and $k$ are linear functions, so the "reference points" don't make a difference.

Comment: They are academic as far as the equation goes, yes, but the choice of datum is important from the point of view of the temperature at which the material properties are linearised.

Comment: $(C+DT)^{-1}$ may be expanded as $$\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} (-D)^n(T-\frac{1-C}{D})^n = \sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} (-\beta)^n(T-T_1)^n$$ such that $\frac{q_v}{k}$ may be written as an infinite order polynomial in $T$. I don't know whether the quadratic approximate form is any more soluble?